# How to convert Fragment code to Activity code

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I want to convert this fragment to activity please help me !

public class MenuCategoryFragment extends Fragment {

```
private static final String TAG = MenuCategoryFragment.class.getSimpleName();

private RecyclerView recyclerView;

public MenuCategoryFragment() {
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getActivity().setTitle(getString(R.string.manu_categories));
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu_category, container, false);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.food_menu);
    GridLayoutManager mGrid = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mGrid);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    return view;
}
```

}

Comment: Copy it to an activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your Activity Class.

```
public class YourActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_menu_category);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.food_menu);
    GridLayoutManager mGrid = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mGrid);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

}
}
```

One last thing, make sure you declare your "Activity" class in "AndroidMenifest".